# Recursive compression with imagejpeg, imagetruecolor from gd library

Tags: php, recursion, gdlib

I have this code i wrote to recursively compress an image until it fall within the size range that i want. For some reason it wont work. Help!!!

```
public function compress4($src,$dest,$file_size, $count = 1){
    $info = getimagesize($src);
    if($info['mime'] == "image/jpeg"){
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    }
    else if($info['mime'] == "image/png"){
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    }
    else if($info['mime'] == "image/gif"){
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($src);
    }
    if($file_size > 1000){
        $quality = 50;
    }       
    else {
        echo "file size acceptable <br>";
        return $src;
    }
    echo "file has been compressed at $quality" . "%<br>";
    imagejpeg($image,$dest,$quality);
    imagedestroy($image);
    echo $dest . "<br>";
    $file_size = round(filesize($dest)/1024);
    echo "filesize: $file_size and count: $count<br>";
    if ($file_size > 1000 && $count <= 5){
        echo "file size too large<br>";
        echo "file too big for thumbnail: $file_size" . "kb<br>Starting compression number $count<br><br>";
        $this->compress4($src,$src,$file_size, ++$count);
    }
    return $dest;
}
```

all i have discovered is that in gets into an indefinite loop because i cant get the filesizes after the first compression. Below is a link to a snapshop of the output. I had to add a counter just to control the indefinite loop.

[link to image showing output after executing code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlG26.png)

Comment: The result of `filesize` gets cached, so you should call [`clearstatcache`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

> all i have discovered is that in gets into an indefinite loop because i cant get the filesizes after the first compression.

The result of filesize gets cached. (Or to say, the result of the underlying file system calls do, would probably be more accurate; this affects not only filesize, but several other functions that get information about a file/folder as well.)

So you should call [`clearstatcache`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) in each iteration, so that when you check the file size afterwards you get the actual current value.